# csvParser.getRecords() returns empty when there are records in CSVParser

Tags: java, csv, java-8, apache-commons-csv

I'm using following dependency for reading the csv file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is the code that I've written to read the csv file:

```
Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(file.getPath()));
CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT);
for(CSVRecord csvRecord: csvParser) {
     System.out.println(csvRecord.get(0));
}
```

I can read every line from the csv file by the above method. But csvParser.getRecords(); returns empty. I want the total number of lines in the CSV file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Read the [getRecords() 
javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html#getRecords--) carefully (emphasis is mine):

> The returned content starts at **the current parse-position** in the
>   stream.

You said :

> But csvParser.getRecords(); returns empty. I want the total number of
>   lines in the CSV file. How can I do this?

You have to invoke `csvParser.getRecords().size();` before iterating  records. Then iterate them.

For example :

```
List<Records> records = csvParser.getRecords();
int nbRecords = records.size();
for(CSVRecord csvRecord: records) {
     System.out.println(csvRecord.get(0));
}
```

Comment: It should be assigned to some list variable. That should be fine. "for(CSVRecord csvRecord: csvParser.getRecords()) {   System.out.println(csvRecord.get(0)); }" gives empty.

Comment: I had the problem that when i invoked size() rest list was then empty. Without invoking size() the list was filled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can `stream` evrything you can do `for` on, so you should be able to

```
StreamSupport.stream(csvParser.spliterator(), false).count()
```

NB: It will still allocate records (unnecessarily) this way.

Answer (score 0):

[univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) has a built-in `getInputDimension` routine that gives you that information - it should be at least 6 times faster than whatever you try with commons-csv.

This one liner will do it:

```
int lines = new CsvRoutines().getInputDimension(new File("/path/to/your.csv")).rowCount();
```

Hope this helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache 2.0 license)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be assigned to array list , because CSVParser free the memory of the List `

```
CSVParser csvParser = CSVParser.parse(multipartFileStream, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII,
                CSVFormat.EXCEL);
                List<CSVRecord> listCsvRecord =  new ArrayList<>();
                listCsvRecord.addAll(csvParser.getRecords());
            `
```